# Does a Windows Platform based server with IIS7.5 support .htaccess

Tags: asp.net, html, .htaccess, redirect

I am new to .htaccess concept. I have a website hosted on a **Windows server with IIS 7.5**.
I want know **if .htaccess is supported on it or not actually** I want to resolve canonical url issue with it, I even tried creating .htaccess and ran it on the server but did not worked.

My **hosting provider offers me even Linux server** also so what should i do to achieve .htaccess functionality should i migrate to linux server please note that my website is created in aspx with some page in html also.

I know canonical issue can be resolved through web.config file also but even that is not working.

please help me.

Regards,
Shashikant

Comment: Take a look at this questions and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386521/how-to-implement-url-routing-with-php-iis

Answer (score 0):

If your website is an ASP.NET website (.aspx) .htaccess files are of no relevance to you, and you should usually be running your website on a Windows Server.

.htaccess files are for Apache web servers and although they can be used on IIS 7.5 e.g. for a PHP-based site like Prestashop you would require a third-party plugin to utilise the .htaccess files.

The Windows Server IIS7.5 closest equivalent is the web.config file.